# My Mongos can't authenticate to my replica set

Tags: replication, mongodb, configuration, sharding, mongodb-4.0

I have 3 config servers in a replica set and when I use the command: sudo mongos --configdb crs/the 3 config servers:port# --keyfile "Keyfile",

I keep getting this error:
[mongosMain] Unable to reach primary for set crs
[mongosMain] Cannot reach any nodes for set crs.

I have checked that all the config servers are online and functional, I have checked the firewall.

This is on AWS linux.

Comment: Try `rs.status()` on the config server. On your mongos machine check with `curl --connect-timeout 10 --show-error hostname:27019` whether the config hosts are really reachable.

Comment: Use "-character round list of config servers  --configdb "crs/node1:27017,node2:27017,node3:27017"